# 424 Object Required error with VBA Vlookup

Tags: vba, excel, vlookup

I'm working through the below script to eventually pull a range of data from a data query to a separate worksheet based on the value entered in an **`inputbox`**, however I keep encountering a 424 error - object required.

To test whether this is working I'm trying to display a message box so i can start the next phase however the script keeps failing at `Vlookup`

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()


Dim NextRelease As String

If MsgBox("Would you like to promote the next release in batch?", vbQuestion + vbYesNo, "Promote the next release?") = vbYes Then
NextRelease = InputBox("Please enter the date of the next release", "Next Release", "DD/MM/YYYY")
ReleaseDate = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(NextRelease, TRELINFO.Range("A2:B4"), 1, False)
If NextRelease = ReleaseDate Then
MsgBox ("Working")
```

Please could someone provide an answer as to why this is happening and hopefully resolve this issue.
Thank you in advance!

Comment: what line is the error coming up at?

Comment: `TRELINFO` this is the error. Do you have any sheet with code name `TRELINFO` or do you have a worksheet type variable which is set to any worksheet?

Comment: @cyboashu - The sheet name is TRELINFO and the data query is also named TRELINFO. To avoid any confusion i have now renamed the sheet temporarily to TRELINFO2 yet the same error is being returned.

Comment: I have also tried prefixing the range with the sheet name yet no luck. `Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(NextRelease, Sheets("TRELINFO").Range("A2:A4"), 1, False)`

Comment: that's strange, 424 should be gone now. No clue why thats happening, with correct sheet name.

Comment: Sorry @cyboashu, the error message is now  a 1004 error - Application defined or Object defined error, is this a step in the right direction?

Comment: :) yup, now your vlookup is failing. Make sure you can run vlookup manually on the data set.

Comment: `NextRelease` is a string value: you cannot look that up in a table of dates...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding `Set TRELINFO = Sheets.("Sheet1")` before you refer to the worksheet. Replacing 'Sheet1' with the name of your TRELINFO sheet.

Edit: The VLOOKUP will return an error if there is no value present in the first row of your table which matches the user input. Below works for me after testing on a table (with date formatting) in excel.

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()

Set trelinfo = Sheets("TRELINFO")
Dim NextRelease As Long

If MsgBox("Would you like to promote the next release in batch?", vbQuestion + vbYesNo, "Promote the next release?") = vbYes Then _
NextRelease = CLng(CDate(InputBox("Please enter the date of the next release", "Next Release", "DD/MM/YYYY")))

checkblank = WorksheetFunction.CountIf(trelinfo.Range("A2:A4"), NextRelease)

If checkblank <> 0 Then
    ReleaseDate = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(NextRelease, trelinfo.Range("A2:B4"), 1, False)
    If NextRelease = ReleaseDate Then _
    MsgBox "Working"

Else
    MsgBox "Release not found"

End If

End Sub
```

Comment: I have tried adding `Set TRELINFO = Worksheets("TRELINFO")` yet the same error is being returned.

Comment: I have just noticed after adding the above the error message being returned is now a 1004 error - Application defined or Object defined error

Comment: The 1004 error is likely due to your VLOOKUP not being able to return a value. Have you tried submitting a value which is definitely located in A2 to A4?

Comment: Perfect! this is working like a charm! Thank you for all your help and thank you everyone else.

Answer (score 1):

NextRelease is a string value: you cannot look that up in a table of dates without first converting it to a Double.

Since you're not returning a value from your VLOOKUP you can more simply use MATCH.

Dropping the `WorksheetFunction` allows you to test the return value for an error, instead of raising a run-time error if there's no match.

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()

Dim NextRelease As String

If MsgBox("Would you like to promote the next release in batch?", _
          vbQuestion + vbYesNo, "Promote the next release?") = vbYes Then

    NextRelease = InputBox("Please enter the date of the next release", _
                           "Next Release", "DD/MM/YYYY")

    If not IsError(Application.Match(CDbl(DateValue(NextRelease), _
                   TRELINFO.Range("A2:B4"), 0) Then

         MsgBox ("Working")
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that the sheet TRELINFO exists or is named correctly. It appears the function can't find that worksheet.

Comment: I have triple checked the name of the sheet and can confirm all is correct.

Comment: Noticed the 1004 error in other comments, make sure that the value exists in the lookup range. VLookup will throw the 1004 error if the value would return #NA or #Value when using it in the spreadsheet.

Answer (score 0):

Just use this instead

```
ReleaseDate = Application.VLookup(NextRelease, Worksheets("trelinfo").Range("A2:B4"), 1, False)
```

I encountered this error before when using VLookUp function. I just remove the WorksheetFunction then it works